# Using EventStore, can I create a new iCal calendary type?

Tags: ios, ios5, icalendar, eventkit

So in my app I rely heavily on `iCal`, and I can add events using `EventStore`, but only to the "defaultCalendarForNewEvents". I want to make a new calendar just for the events I create in the app, let's say MyApp calendar, which would behave much like the `iCal` calendars like "Home", "Work", etc.

Is there a way to do this programmatically?

Right now, I've tried this:

```
EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

NSArray *calendars = [eventStore calendars];
BOOL calendarHasBeenInitialized = NO;
for(NSCalendar *cal in calendars)
{
    if([cal.calendarIdentifier isEqualToString:@"Workout Tracker"])
    {
        calendarHasBeenInitialized = YES;
    }
}
if(!calendarHasBeenInitialized)
{
    NSString *string = [[NSString alloc] initWithString:@"Workout Tracker"];
    NSCalendar *workoutCalendar = (__bridge NSCalendar *)(CFCalendarCreateWithIdentifier(kCFAllocatorSystemDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef)string));
    EKCalendar *ekcalendar = (EKCalendar *)workoutCalendar;
    NSError *error;
    [eventStore saveCalendar:ekcalendar commit:YES error:&error];
}
```

This is called in my `App Delegate` where if the calendar is not in the calendars array, I attempt to create it. This however, does not work.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs, use EKCalendar's [`+calendarWithEventStore:`](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DataManagement/Reference/EKCalendarClassRef/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/clm/EKCalendar/calendarWithEventStore%3a) method to create a new calendar in the event store you specify. I expect it'd go like this:

```
EKCalendar *newCalendar = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore:eventStore];
```

Comment: While this does seem to create a new calendar, I attempted using this and then setting my event's calendar to this new calendar I created. This, however, did not work, as I get an error when I try to save the event to the eventStore.